# Is there any way to connect 'Samsung galaxy tab 2 p3100' to a monitor

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7, external-display

i want to know how to connect the galaxy tab 2 p3100 to my monitor through hdmi or dvi interface. is it possible or not. i tried google but can't find any solution.

Comment: I think it needs samsung's proprietary 11-pin MHL adaptor to output HDMI. Ordinary MHL adaptors won't work as it only has 5-pins. I dont own a galaxy tab so take my suggestion with a pinch of salt

Comment: @forums - The Tab 2 uses a stupid Apple-like connector, not a normal microUSB.  The 11-pin thing is for the Galaxy S3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 does not support any form of video out.  The necessary hardware was not included in the design for cost-cutting reasons.  Only the 10.1 has MHL capability.

source: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=37032295&postcount=110